# WPF ListView Thousand Separator

Tags: wpf, data-binding, string-formatting

I want to display numbers i thousand separated format. Numbers are displayed in a Column of ListView control. I've the following xaml code, but it doesn't even compile!

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Total" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PaidValue, StringFormat={0:0,0}}" />
```

From my c# point of view, {0:0,0} is a correct format to do this, right? What is wrong with this?

The error is totally unrelated : "Unknown build error, 'Key Can not be null' pointing to the same line of xaml code. If tried other variants of the same format with no use.

Comment: Is the GridViewColumn in the resources section? Does it need an x:key?

Comment: no, it inside of an <GridView> tag. Everything works just fine without string formatter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OKay, I found a way to do this. I need to say that, in fact I DO have SP1 installed, so as a lot of blog posts are implying {0:c} should work, while it does not and will end up producing the same compile-time error! Here's how I did it:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PaidValue, StringFormat='0,0'}" />
```

Compiles and works with no problem. I wonder if other binding's StringFormat values are still valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Total" 
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PaidValue, StringFormat={0:c}}" />
```

Will format the number to the native string currency.

You can find more numeric formats from [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/NumericFormattingCustomFormatStringsSectionSeparator.htm)

Comment: this, also, does not compile! same error as above! I checked and I actually HAVE installed SP1